# Django Project for creating events

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Before I continue developing this project, I just wanted to make sure I'm going about creating the views and tests in a "proper manner" or if I am completely fudging this up. Also, is it better to use the Django forms over sending information via Ajax, or does it not matter?

[Repo link](https://github.com/CCecilia/eliteDangerousEvents.git) if you wanna check out the entire project.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'page': 'index',
        'coverHeading': 'Search Events'
    }
    return render(request, 'html/index.html', context)


def signin(request):
    context = {
        'page': 'signin'
    }
    return render(request, 'html/signin.html', context)


def createEventPage(request):
    context = {
        'page': 'createEvent',
        'coverHeading': 'Create Event'
    }
    return render(request, 'html/createEvent.html', context)


def allEvents(request):
    # Get Events
    events = Event.objects.all()

    context = {
        'page': 'allEvents',
        'coverHeading': 'All Events',
        'events': events
    }
    return render(request, 'html/allEvents.html', context)


def myEvents(request):
    # Dec  Vars
    user = request.user

    # redirect to signin page if user not found
    try:
        events = Event.objects.filter(creator=user)
    except TypeError:
        return redirect('signin')

    context = {
        'page': 'myEvents',
        'coverHeading': 'My Events',
        'events': events
    }
    return render(request, 'html/myEvents.html', context)


def editEvent(request, event_id):
    # Dec  Vars
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    context = {
        'page': 'editEvent',
        'coverHeading': 'Edit Event',
        'event': event
    }
    return render(request, 'html/editEvent.html', context)


# AJAX


def register(request):
    # dec vars
    username = str(request.POST['register-username']).lower()
    email = str(request.POST['register-email']).lower()
    password = str(request.POST['register-password'])

    # check if username or email is used
    username_check = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    email_check = User.objects.filter(email=email)

    if username_check:
        response = {
            'status': 'fail',
            'error_msg': 'username already in use'
        }
    elif email_check:
        response = {
            'status': 'fail',
            'error_msg': 'email already in use'
        }
    elif len(password) < 8:
        response = {
            'status': 'fail',
            'error_msg': 'password must be atleast 8 characters long'
        }
    else:
        # create user
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

        # login user
        login(request, user)

        # create response
        response = {
            'status': 'success',
        }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def loginUser(request):
    # dec vars
    username = request.POST['signin-username']
    password = request.POST['signin-password']
    # Auth user
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        login(request, user)
        # create response
        response = {
            'status': 'success'
        }
    else:
        # create response
        response = {
            'status': 'fail'
        }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def logoutUser(request):
    # log out user
    logout(request)

    # send to home page
    return redirect('index')


def searchEvents(request):
    # dec vars
    event_search = json.loads(request.body)['event_search']

    # filter for matching events and serialize for json
    event_search_results = list(Event.objects.filter(
        name__icontains=event_search
    ).values(
        'id',
        'name',
        'event_type',
        'start_date',
        'attendees'
    ))

    # create response
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
        'event_search_results': event_search_results
    }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def eventDetails(request):
    # get event
    event_id = json.loads(request.body)['event_id']
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)

    # serialize json
    serialized_event = serializers.serialize('json', [event])

    # create response
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
        'event': serialized_event
    }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def eventJoin(request):
    # get event
    user_id = int(request.POST['user-id'])
    event_id = int(request.POST['event-id'])
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)

    # add user to event
    event.attendees.add(user)

    # get updated attendance count
    attendance = event.attendees.all().count()

    # create response
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
        'attendance': attendance
    }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def createEvent(request):
    # dec vars
    event_title = str(request.POST['event-title']).title()
    event_type = str(request.POST['event-type'])
    event_location = str(request.POST['event-location'])
    event_description = str(request.POST['event-description'])
    event_start_date = str(request.POST['event-start-date'])
    event_start_time = str(request.POST['event-start-time'])
    event_end_date = str(request.POST['event-end-date'])
    event_end_time = str(request.POST['event-end-time'])
    creator = request.user

    # create event
    Event.objects.create(
        name=event_title,
        event_type=event_type,
        creator=creator,
        location=event_location,
        description=event_description,
        start_date=event_start_date,
        start_time=event_start_time,
        end_date=event_end_date,
        end_time=event_end_time
    )

    # #create response
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
    }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def updateEvent(request, event_id):
    # dec vars
    event_title = str(request.POST['event-title']).title()
    event_type = str(request.POST['event-type'])
    event_location = str(request.POST['event-location'])
    event_description = str(request.POST['event-description'])
    event_start_date = str(request.POST['edit-event-start-date'])
    event_start_time = str(request.POST['edit-event-start-time'])
    event_end_date = str(request.POST['edit-event-end-date'])
    event_end_time = str(request.POST['edit-event-end-time'])
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)

    # Update Event
    event.name = event_title
    event.event_type = event_type
    event.location = event_location
    event.description = event_description

    # only update new dates/times
    if event_start_date:
        event.start_date = event_start_date

    if event_end_date:
        event.end_date = event_end_date

    if event_start_time:
        event.start_time = event_start_time

    if event_end_time:
        event.end_time = event_end_time

    # Save updated event
    event.save()

    # create response
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
    }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def removeEvent(request):
    # dec vars
    event_id = json.loads(request.body)['event_id']
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)

    # delete event
    event.delete()

    # create response
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
    }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)


def searchSystems(request):
    system_query = json.loads(request.body)['system_query']
    results = list(SolarSystem.objects.filter(name__icontains=system_query).values('name')[:5])

    # create response
    response = {
        'status': 'success',
        'results': results
    }

    # send reponse JSON
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

tests.py

```
   class EventModelTests(TestCase):
    c = Client()

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):


        # dec vars
        today = timezone.now()
        tomorrow = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1)
        start_date = today.date()
        start_time = today.time()
        end_date = tomorrow.date()
        end_time = start_time

        # create auth user
        User.objects.create(
            username='TestUser',
            email='test@user.com',
            password='password'
        )

        # create attendees for event
        for i in range(5):
            username = 'TestUser%s' % i
            email = 'test%s@user.com' % i
            User.objects.create(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password='password'
            )

        # Create Events
        for i in range(5):
            event_name = 'Test Event %s' % i
            Event.objects.create(
                name=event_name,
                event_type='Combat',
                creator=User.objects.get(pk=1),
                start_date=start_date,
                start_time=start_time,
                end_date=end_date,
                end_time=end_time,
                location='Sol',
                date_created=timezone.now(),
                description=lorem.paragraph()
            )

    def test_event_associated_to_auth_user(self):
        # check if event will return creator
        event = Event.objects.get(pk=1)
        user = event.creator
        self.assertEqual(user.id, 1)

    def test_attendees_added_to_event(self):
        # exclude creator from attendees
        test_attendees = User.objects.all().exclude(pk=1)
        event = Event.objects.get(pk=1)

        # add attendees to event
        for attendee in test_attendees:
            event.attendees.add(attendee)

        self.assertEqual(event.attendees.all().count(), 5)

    def test_myEvents_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('/allEvents/')
        # check reponse and template
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # cehck all events are returned
        self.assertTrue(len(response.context['events']) == 5)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'html/allEvents.html')

    def test_editEvent_view_(self):
        response = self.client.get('/event/edit/1/')
        # check reponse and template
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'html/editEvent.html')
        # check correct event is returned
        correct_event = Event.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['event'], correct_event)

    def test_search_events(self):
        # Check event search
        response = self.c.post(
            '/event/search/', 
            json.dumps({'event_search': 'Test Event'}),
            'json',
            HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest',
        )
        event_search_results = json.loads(response.content)['event_search_results']
        # Check event objs are returned
        self.assertEqual(len(event_search_results), 5)
        # check event objs have values
        for i in range(len(event_search_results)):
            self.assertFalse(event_search_results[i]['id'] == '')
            self.assertFalse(event_search_results[i]['name'] == '')
            self.assertFalse(event_search_results[i]['event_type'] == '')
            self.assertEqual(event_search_results[i]['attendees'], None)

    def test_event_details(self):
        # Check event search
        response = self.c.post(
            '/event/details/', 
            json.dumps({'event_id': 1}),
            'json',
            HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest',
        )
        event = json.loads(response.content)['event']

        # Check event obj is returned
        self.assertTrue(event)


class RenderViewsTests(TestCase):

    def test_index_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('')
        # check reponse and template
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'html/index.html')

    def test_createEvent_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('/createEvent/')
        # check reponse and template
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'html/createEvent.html')

    def test_allEvents_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('/myEvents/')
        # check redirect for user not signed in
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_signin_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('/signin/')
        # check redirect for user not signed in
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'html/signin.html')


class AjaxViewsTests(TestCase):
    c = Client()

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        User.objects.create(
            username='testuser',
            email='testuser@email.com',
            password='password'
        )

    def test_ajax_register_success(self):
        # Check register success
        response = self.c.post('/register/', {
            'register-username': 'testuser1',
            'register-email': 'testuser1@email.com',
            'register-password': 'password'
        })
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['status'], 'success')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_ajax_register_username_in_use(self):
        # Check register failed  username taken
        response = self.c.post('/register/', {
            'register-username': 'testuser',
            'register-email': 'testuser@email.com',
            'register-password': 'password'
        })
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['status'], 'fail')
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['error_msg'], 'username already in use')

    def test_ajax_register_email_in_use(self):
        # Check register failed email in use
        response = self.c.post('/register/', {
            'register-username': 'testuser1',
            'register-email': 'testuser@email.com',
            'register-password': 'password'
        })
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['status'], 'fail')
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['error_msg'], 'email already in use')

    def test_ajax_register_password_length(self):
        # Check register failed  password length
        response = self.c.post('/register/', {
            'register-username': 'testuser2',
            'register-email': 'testuser2@email.com',
            'register-password': 'pass'
        })
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['status'], 'fail')
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['error_msg'], 'password must be atleast 8 characters long')

    def test_ajax_login_fail(self):
        # Check login fail
        response = self.c.post('/login/', {
            'signin-username': 'testuser5000',
            'signin-password': 'password'
        })
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['status'], 'fail')
```